# Is it possible to make a custom metric about a BigQuery SQL query?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-monitoring

Because there is no GCP Monitoring metric that can count the total number of rows in a BigQuery table I want to create a custom metric for that. My goal is to use that metric for  visualization in a dashboard.

According to the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#monitoring_create_metric-java) you can write a java script using the Monitoring API to create a custom metric.
In addition to that I was wondering if I can use the BigQuery API and do a simple sql query to count the number of rows in a BigQuery table and use this as data points for the custom metric.

Is this possible?

Thanks for any answer in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course, you can add a side jobs that create these custom metrics. In addition, on BigQuery, when you perform a `select count(*) from TABLE`, you pay nothing because this data is retrieve from the table metadata.

Comment: I think that you can also get the rows for the table you want using the API:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#Table
Look for the "numRows": string

The pipe could look something like:
Big Query API Call -> Java app that does the API call and creates and sends the metric you would get from the API and "numRows" -> Monitoring Dashboard that draws the metric.

Comment: And adding to Guillaume's approach which is really nice, the count reaching the metadata server could look something like:

Metadata server Count -> Java app that reaches the server and then creates and sends the metric to monitoring -> Monitoring dashboard that draws the metric.

I also wanted to share this document with you:
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#monitoring_write_timeseries-java
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics

Comment: Thanks @CarloC. for your comment. I didn't check the API, but it's also a smart idea!!

Comment: Thank you for the replies so far Guillaume, @CarloC. I'm wondering if creating the custom metric is also  possible without a java app. I found this terraform metric descriptor (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/monitoring_metric_descriptor.html) and after creating the example resource I was able to find the example custom metric in the Metric explorer. Is it somehow possible now to use the bigquery sql count query for this metric as my data points without involving a java app? Or are there other ways to create this custom metric without the need of a cloudfunction or a java app?

Comment: I think that the you should at least use one of the two, so something gets the number of rows and sends it to monitoring. Monitoring can't do this by itself since the total number_of_rows is not a monitored metric.


https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/resources#tag_bigquery_dataset
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-bigquery

I would not know about the terraform metric.

Comment: Thanks again @CarloC. I hope this question is not too late but I have a problem understanding how to execute the code. You mentioned "Java app that does the API call and creates and sends the metric" for that. Can you elaborate what you mean with java app? In the doc cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/… you shared is example java code to create a custom metric and write data to it. But I don't understand where and how in Google Cloud I have to run/execute this code.